# Передать значение в slider Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Добрый день.

Есть [стандартный](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) jquery-slider:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    range:"min",
    value:100000,
    min:1000,
    max:10000,
    step:1000,
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        val = $( "#slider" ).slider("value");
    },
    slide:function(event,ui)
    {   credit=ui.value;
        $('#cards_summ_pb').html(credit)
    }
});
```

и есть обычный переключатель , который принимает значение например либо 10000 либо 20000

Как сделать, чтобы значение переключателя передавалось в условия слайдера в параметр max? Идея такая, что в зависимости от значения этого переключателя должен изменяться диапазон слайдера.

Comment: `$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "max", 10000 );` ?

Comment: @br3t т.е. вместо 10000 в вашей конструкции я подставляю переменную, которая меняется в зависимости от переключателя, так?

Comment: именно, вы правы

Comment: попробовал, работает, отлично, сделайте в виде ответа и я поставлю галочку, и лично от меня спасибо

Comment: br3t, а вы не подскажиет, как через переключатель передавать салйдеру определенное значение? $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 10000 ); не работет так как нужно

Comment: Как у вас выполнен переключатель?

Comment: @br3t обычный radio input -  работает вот так $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", 10000 ), причем красиво очень работает, плавно лифтик уходит в нужное значение. Еще раз спасибо за отзывчивость!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить параметры уже созданного слайдера можно с помощью метода [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-option). В частности, для изменения максимума достаточно вызвать метод со следующими параметрами:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "max", 10000 );
```